How to properly make HTTPS server requests with pygbag without getting asyncio.run() error?
how can HTTPS server requests be made using pygbag?
In a discussion : https://github.com/pygame-web/pygbag/discussions/120,
they suggested using:
from pygbag.support.cross.aio.fetch import RequestHandler

However, when I try this approach locally, it throws the following error:
asyncio.run(main())
File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 33, in run
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

Here is a simplified version of my code:
import asyncio
import json
from pygbag.support.cross.aio.fetch import RequestHandler

async def send_request(data):
    handler = RequestHandler()
    try:
        response = await handler.post(f"{BASE_URL}/endpoint", data=data)
        if response:
            print("POST /endpoint: Success")
            response_data = json.loads(response)
            result = response_data.get('result')
            print("Result:", result)
            return result
        else:
            print("POST /endpoint: Failed")
            return None
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to post data:", e)
        return None

# Example data
data = {"key": "value"}

# Function to run the coroutine in the asyncio event loop
async def main():
    result = await send_request(data)
    if result:
        print("The computed result is:", result)
    else:
        print("No result could be retrieved.")

# Start the event loop to run the main function
asyncio.run(main())

I'm getting the following warning and error:
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

